# Adjusting the vertical position of the text cursor (relative to the text itself) in an HTML input

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've noticed that the metrics of some web fonts cause very poor vertical alignment with the text in HTML input fields (see the image below, which is a rendering of "Gill Sans" obtained via MyFonts).
[image: text cursor with poor vertical alignment]
I believe this is an issue with the font itself, and therefore cannot be solved with CSS (although I've included the CSS tag in case I'm wrong about that). **Adjusting the line height does not solve the issue**, because line height affects the positioning of the text and cursor *together*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing the vertical metrics using [Transfonter](https://transfonter.org/) (be sure to check "Fix vertical metrics"). To figure out what the tool was doing, I used the `TTX` command ([FontTools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools)) to convert the original and fixed fonts into XML format. It seems that this tool is adjusting the ascent and descent values in the HHEA and OS/2 tables (possibly by iterating over all glyphs and finding the maximum ascent and minimum descent values).

**Original HHEA Table**

```
<hhea>
  ...
  <ascent value="750"/>
  <descent value="-250"/>
  ...
</hhea>
```

**Fixed HHEA Table**

```
<hhea>
  ...
  <ascent value="911"/>
  <descent value="-230"/>
  ...
</hhea>
```

**Original OS/2 Table**

```
<OS_2>
  ...
  <sTypoAscender value="750"/>
  <sTypoDescender value="-250"/>
  <usWinAscent value="926"/>
  <usWinDescent value="274"/>
  ...
</OS_2>
```

**Fixed OS/2 Table**

```
<OS_2>
  ...
  <sTypoAscender value="911"/>
  <sTypoDescender value="-230"/>
  <usWinAscent value="911"/>
  <usWinDescent value="230"/>
 ...
</OS_2>
```

[image: fixed cursor position]